# Как потоку обрабатывать несколько ссылок?

Tags: python, многопоточность, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь сделать быстрый многопоточный парсер ссылок, в идеале чтобы каждая ссылка обрабатывалась в своем потоке каждую секунду. Но 30 потоков сильно снижают скорость.

```
def parser(url):
...

def threads():
urls = [url1, url2, url3, ur4]
    for url in urls:
        threading.Thread(target=parser, args=(url,)).start()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы один поток обрабатывал к примеру две ссылки?

Comment: В парсинге основная затрата время это запрос. Напишите, что вы используете для отправки запросов

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Dt4XU3Xr

Comment: по коду не понятно, но подозреваю что это библиотека requests. Чтобы повысить скорость парсинга, вам нужно использовать асинхронные библиотеки, например aiohttp async

Comment: request, попробую другие библиотеки, спасибо

Comment: Посмотрите этот пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c1a861063bf824416e854a52dcc1aa286ed6f310/multithreading__threading__examples/example%20multiprocessing.dummy/hello_world_with_result__requests.py В нем каждый url обрабатывался в отдельном потоке, но лимит одновременно запущенных потоков существует и его можно менять

Comment: @danilshik, вы хотите сказать что если одновременно запустить в нескольких потоках скачивание через requests.get, то пока один из requests.get выполняет скачивание, остальные ждут его? А как помогут aiohttp/async? Они умеют держать несколько одновременных коннектов и по чучуть с каждого из коннекта считывать/передавать данные?

Comment: @gil9red Вы использовали пул потоков, в определенной мере я с вами согласен, он существенно повысит скорость парсинга, но он все же будет ниже, чем если бы он был написан на асинхронных библитеках

Comment: @danilshik, а почему? Можете это объяснить? :)

Comment: @gil9red ну давайте проведем эксперимент, возьмем 1 любой сайт (например какой-нибудь небольшой интернет-магазин)(да простят нас админы сайта), и спарсим его, и сравним кто быстрее, requests + bs4+ multiprocessing.dummy (ну или любой другой пул потоков) или async + aiohttp + bs4 + concurrent.futures (threedpoolexecutor)

Comment: @danilshik, c multiprocessing.dummy время парсинга уменьшилось в 2 раза для теста на 5 url: https://gist.github.com/gil9red/93910663cd86d1b8260e8c0973e28198 (с мультипроцессингом не удалось проверить, но заготовки остались). Можете попробовать и добавить туда реализацию с async + aiohttp :) PS. особо не нагружайте стек, а то он будет ругаться на `Too many requests` ;)

Comment: @gil9red https://github.com/danilshik/TestSpeedParsing/blob/master/test_speed_parsing.py  И чем больше будет список, и чем дольше будет выполняться запрос, тем асинхронный будет быстрее

Comment: @danilshik, круто :) асинхронный вариант очень быстрый